# What is the function of "unmodified" in "It is passed unmodified to the next block"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

What I have learnt so far, an adverb can be placed adjacent to a verb. For example,

> It is directly passed to the next block.

or

> It is passed directly to the next block.

I found a sentence as follows.

> It is passed unchanged to the next block.

Why is it possible to place an adjective "unmodified" here? And what is its function?

Can I rephrase it as follows?

> It is passed unmodifiedly to the next block.

Comment: In, say, *I drink **neat** whisky*, it's obvious that the highlighted word is an adjective. Maybe it's not so obvious that ***Neat** whisky is drunk in my house* AND *Whisky is drunk **neat** in my house* are BOTH ALSO adjectival, but so far as I'm concerned that's all there is to it. And in the same vein, ***unchanged / unmodified*** are also adjectives in your context (and to a first approximation, ***unmodifiedly*** simply isn't a valid term in English).

Comment: "Unchanged" is an adjective. It's predicative here, i.e. even though it is located in the verb phrase as a modifying adjunct, it refers to the subject "it". Its function is thus 'predicative adjunct'. The same applies to your example with the adjective "unmodified".

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you for  your insightful comments. One more question, is it possible to swap the `passed` and `unmodified` without changing the meaning? For example, `It is passed unmodified to the next block` is rephrased as `It is unmodified passed to the next block`.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity No. adjectives functioning as predicative adjuncts only occur after the verb, never before.

Comment: @BillJ: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> It is passed directly ...

the "directly" is an adverb telling you how it is passed, so an adverb modifying the verb.

In

> It is passed unmodified

the "ummodified" is an adjective telling you about *it*, so an adjective.

There's no grammatical reason to object to placing it after the verb.

I wouldn't want to read about passing it unmodifiably unless there were some technical reason to describe the passing that way.

(This is a less technical version of the comment from @BillJ .)